# How to fill formula horizontally but increment cell references vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I need to populate a table with horizontally referring to values that are vertically from another table

In the horizontal table I'm doing the following

```
='Tab 3x3'!G10
```

But when I drag to the side it increments the column, not the cell. It would need him to continue G11, G12 .. and so on.

I've tried to anchor ($) in every way but it's no use. I also tried using TRANSPOSE that even worked but it got a mess, I would need the same reference as the above formula. I also researched and found a staff using Offset, but I could not quite understand.

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: btw, transpose would also work, but you'd need to use it as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX('Tab 3x3'!$G:$G,COLUMN(A:A)+9)
```

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
=INDIRECT("'tab 3x3'!"&ADDRESS(COLUMNS($A$7:E7)+5,7),TRUE)
```

Or in light of the comment from Scott, use

```
=OFFSET('tab 3x3'!$G$10,COLUMNS('tab 3x3'!$G$10:G10)-1,0)
```

Comment: FYI: both INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile formulas and overusing them will see an impact in the calc times of the whole application if the workbook is open.